# Getting basic protest info from events page with Python and BeautifulSoup 3

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull out some information on a website with a list of protests with BS3, but I'm struggling a bit to remember how to correctly get everything out. Eventually, I want each event to go into a csv with the following info:

datetime as '2011-01-10', protest link '012371', name of the protest 'Cattle Rancher's Demo', location id '1728', location name 'City Hall', and most important of all, the country-name 'Madagascar'.

the page's code is as follows:

```
<li><article class="protest"><div class="rdf5"><div itemscope itemtype="Protest"><span style="display:none;"><time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2011-01-10T00:00">2011-01-10T00:00</time></span><p class="flag"><img src=/images/flags/flagger.gif></p> <span> 2011 /</span><br /><a href="/protests/012371" itemprop="url summary">Cattle Rancher's Demo</a> at ​<span itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="organization"><span itemprop="name"><a href=/location.aspx?id=1728>City Hall</a></span> / <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="address"><a href=/protests.aspx?ai=10><span itemprop="country-name">Madagscar</span></a></span></div></article></li>
```

I can successfully pull the individual elements out, e.g.:

```
for event in soup.findAll("span", itemprop="country-name"):
    print event.contents[0]
```

But what I really want is to call each overall article block with class id protest, and then get all the things inside it that I want together ready to write out as a line in the csv. So I tried to do this...

```
for article in soup.findAll('article', class_="protest"):
    country = soup.find("span", itemprop="country-name")
    print country
    datetime = 
    etc
```

...but that fails.
And although I can get it if I just use findAll on 'article'...

```
for article in soup.findAll('article'):
```

...then, it returns the same country hundreds of times because I think it just gets the first one and then pulls country x times (where x is how many article elements there are in the page).

If someone could help me get to the point where it gets, for example, just the country and datetime from each article block, then I'm sure I can figure the rest!

Comment: change `soup.find("span", itemprop="country-name")` to `article.find("span", itemprop="country-name")`

Comment: If you're really using BS3 - you should really consider upgrading to BS4...

Comment: thanks @akashkarothiya I'll try using that method - but could you elaborate with an answer? also thanks Jon, I previously used BS4 on everything else but long story why on the machine I am on it has to be BS3 right now - I will update the code when I shift machine but you're right I should have BS4!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to work with beautiful soup I have found is to just keep adding pieces to extract as you work through the markup - I select a sub element and print it in my loop, and keep selecting bits until I get what I want, then save that to a variable and move on to the next bit I want. I'm not sure how your second loop "fails" - it seems to find the span with the country name just fine, if you had preserved with that way I'm sure you would have got there.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import bs4

html = r"""
<li><article class="protest"><div class="rdf5"><div itemscope itemtype="Protest"><span style="display:none;"><time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2011-01-10T00:00">2011-01-10T00:00</time></span><p class="flag"><img src=/images/flags/flagger.gif></p> <span> 2011 /</span><br /><a href="/protests/012371" itemprop="url summary">Cattle Rancher's Demo</a> at ​<span itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="organization"><span itemprop="name"><a href=/location.aspx?id=1728>City Hall</a></span> / <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="address"><a href=/protests.aspx?ai=10><span itemprop="country-name">Madagscar</span></a></span></div></article></li>
"""

protests = []

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
for article in soup.findAll('article', class_="protest"):
    protest_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(article.find("time").text, "%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M").date()

    protest_link = article.find("a", itemprop="url summary")
    protest_link_id = protest_link["href"].replace("/protests/", "")
    protest_link_name = protest_link.text

    location_wrapper = article.find("span", itemprop="location")
    location_link = location_wrapper.find("span", itemprop="name").find("a")
    location_id = location_link["href"].replace("/location.aspx?id=", "")
    location_name = location_link.text

    country_link = location_wrapper.find("span", itemprop="address").find("a")
    country_name = country_link.find("span", itemprop="country-name").text

    protests.append((protest_link_id, protest_link_name, protest_date, location_id, location_name, country_name))

pd.DataFrame(protests, columns=["protest_link_id", 
                                "protest_link_name", 
                                "protest_date", 
                                "location_id", 
                                "location_name", 
                                "country_name"]).to_csv("protests.csv")
```

I have just noticed you are using bs3 and python 2.6, the above is for bs4 and 3.6 but you should get the idea and be able to translate the process. And actually akash has pinpointed exactly why your loop doesn't work, you need to change your loop to do `article.find(...)`

Comment: Thanks @ken-syme ... just giving it a go :)

Comment: Yes! It basically works! Not having a lot of fun using panda for output bc I want to append but the rest works great... thanks!!! :)